# Do I have to trim my guinea pigs' claws?

Tags: grooming, guinea-pigs

I have posted this question as advice for others.  I used to have my guinea pigs' claws trimmed at the vets some years ago, but I have since found an easier way, and my youngest 'pig who is at least four years old has never needed his claws trimmed.

Answer (score 8):

My solution to this problem was to put a sandstone tile in the cage.  every time the guinea pigs go to their food bowl they shorten their nails just a little, here is the layout:

[image]

and here are their feet, as you can see they are quite healthy:

[image]
[image]

The guinea pigs' pads prevent the claws from getting too short, and the constant wearing down stops them getting too long.

Good points:

- No trimming claws.
- Less stress for your pets.

Bad points:

- Stone is heavy to move when cleaning the cage.
- Animal claws are naturally sharp.
- Because you don't need to groom their claws, 'pigs can become less social.

Comment: I love this solution.  Where did you get the stones though?

Comment: DIY shop, paving section.